# SQL Server: Match Identity Specification of 2 diff columns in 2 diff tables

Tags: sql-server, database, calculated-columns

I'm making a program that has two different tables(well more, but those are the ones I have an issue with). One called SYNPaymentHistory, and the other one called OTHERSPaymentHistory

They have almost the same columns, except the SYNPaymentHistory includes an "ID" number, for each Syndicate. The Other's table is for any *random* payment the company receives other than from the Syndicates

I made a page in which a person fills out a payment application, and when all that is done, it should print out a receipt. Receipts have a SerialNb, which is a Column found in both tables (it's an INT column with Identity Specification that increases by 1, on every input).

My issue is that I want the SerialNb to be synchronized between both of them.

**Ex:** say I just filled out a payment application from a Syndicate, SerialNb on the top of the receipt should say 5001. If I want to fill a payment application from tickets the company earned due to a party, I'd want that receipt to have the SerialNb of 5002.

Is there some way to link 2 columns that are from 2 different tables? I think a WHILE Loop can half-solve the issue, if one of them auto-increases by 1, and the other has a WHILE loop that, if i = SYNHistoryPayment.SerialNb, then i = i + 1 **(i being OTHERSHistoryPayment)** but it wouldn't work out the other way, because SYNHistoryPayment would end up not caring about OTHERSHistoryPayment's values.

Is it, in any way possible, related to diagrams? I couldn't properly understand the usage of diagrams so I'm hoping that's not the way to work it through.

If you need any additional information, I'd love to Edit in the info needed.

Programs used:
Visual Studio 2015, 
SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server has a feature to address just this issue.  It is called a Sequence.  You create a sequence and at any time you can sql server to give you the next value in the sequence.  Each request is guaranteed to have a unique result in increasing order.

Create a sequence -- when you want to make a row in either table get the next value from the sequence and use that.

In addition to solving your problem using a sequence also solves the problem of multiple instances of an application running at the same time.  You don't have to worry -- each instance of an application will get it's own number.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx